# Surface 4 Pro - where are detailed video specs?

Tags: microsoft-surface

Looking at the top end, Core i7 Surface 4 Pro (16GB RAM, 512GB SSD). It has the i7 with Iris graphics.  I will be using it with the new docking station (which has 2 mini dp, so with the device itself I have 3 mini dp outputs).

This is for 2D/business use (not gaming). No fancy 3D support or high frame rate fast-motion needed.

I am trying to determine the answers to the following questions:

1. Will it drive, via a single displayport, a Dell std res display
   of 1600x2560 ?
2. Can it drive two external 4K displays? 3840x2160
   (Dell P2715Q and similar by other mfgrs)
3. Can it drive two external 5k displays? 5120x2880 (Dell UP2715K and similar)

As I understand it, the MiniDP ports are v1.2, and can daisy chain. So what is the max total resolution per MiniDP port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a surface 4 pro, and here are the results:

> > Will it drive, via a single displayport, a Dell std res display of 1600x2560 ?

Yes

> > Can it drive two external 4K displays? 3840x2160 (Dell P2715Q and similar by other mfgrs)

One for sure yes. Two: Looks like yes.

> > Can it drive two external 5k displays? 5120x2880 (Dell UP2715K and similar)

One: Maybe. Two: Appears not. (not certain)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which Iris graphics chip you have.  This site has a list of all of them and a basic rundown of their features: [NotebookCheck.net Tech](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Iris-Graphics-6100.125591.0.html).

From my brief reading, it looks like even the lowest end chip will drive up to 3 displays, with a max resolution of 4K.  I would assume you could drive 2 4K displays, but I doubt you could use 2 (or any) 5K displays.

And yes, it should drive a single DP display.

Comment: It appears the high end surface 4 pro has the Intel Iris 540 video system. I have not yet found detailed video specs, however.